# Tests not showing in TestExplorer using Asp.Net core and Nunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, nunit

Please note I am fairly new to C# as well as testing.

My tests are not showing up in test explorer. I am using visual studio 2015 update 3 as well as using the new asp.net core project structure.

My project.json file looks as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Tests for the earthworm",

  "dependencies": {
    "earthworm": "1.0.0-*",
    "NSubstitute": "2.0.0-rc",
    "NUnit.Runners": "3.4.1",
    "NUnit3TestAdapter": "3.4.1",
    "NUnitLite": "3.4.1",
    "NUnit.Console": "3.4.1",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "commands": {
    "Test": "earthworm.test"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  }
}
```

When I click the run all button in the test explorer, which should find all my tests, I am getting this output :

```
Discovering tests in 'C:\Users\daniel\Repos\earthworm\test\earthworm.test\project.json'
```

and then nothing is showing up in the test explorer. 
I have tried looking at [Testing .NET Core using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/) so it looks like if you are using the newest framework it is possible. I just want to know with dnx451 how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the dependency on `dotnet-test-nunit` and on `NUnit` and have many unneeded references. I am actually surprised that you were able to write unit tests with that list of dependencies, but I guess NUnit gets pulled in by NUnitLite.

Start with a project.json like this,

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Tests for the earthworm",

  "dependencies": {
    "earthworm": "1.0.0-*",
    "NSubstitute": "2.0.0-rc",
    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2"
  },

  "testRunner": "nunit",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks fro the help and great articles btw. So I used the structure you gave me and I had to add back Nunitlite so that autorun function in the main class would work as well as adding the test command to project.json file. This now works fine with dnx however if I try use **run all tests** in visual studio I'm getting Unable to load application or execute command Microsoft.dnx.testhosts and if I add it back it I get the same as in my original post.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to mix the NUnitLite auto run with the .NET Core runner. I haven't tried that combination, but my guess is there is some conflict. You are also running VS 2015 update 3 right?

Comment: Yes I am. If we have the project.json like you suggest do we not need to have that Program.cs as described in [Testing .NET Core using NUnit 3](http://www.alteridem.net/2015/11/04/testing-net-core-using-nunit-3/). I am having an issue as well with dotnet-test-nunit. Once I added this to the project.json and tried to build this was the error I was given **The dependency Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.1 in project earthworm.test does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1**.

Comment: Ah, I think netcore tests require at least 4.6.1, not sure

Comment: @DanielHorne seems to be a bug in "3.4.0-beta-2" uinstall and use "3.4.0-beta-1" instead

Answer (score 0):

If none of above works for you:

> If you're having problems discovering or running tests, you may be a victim of a corrupted runner cache inside Visual Studio. To clear this cache, shut down all instances of Visual Studio, then delete the folder %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions. Also make sure your solution is only linked against a single version of the Visual Studio runner NuGet package (xunit.runner.visualstudio).

From: http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html